# Can we have a single mapping file for multiple POJO in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have three different Java POJO classes. I have one table. Can I use a single `hbm` file for all these three POJO classes?

Comment: all three pojo classes are referring to single table?

Comment: If you have 3 pojos and want to map to a single table then are you having inheritence relationship between them?

Comment: Please state some more information that we are able to help you to solve your problem.